# How to pass complex object to WCF

Tags: .net, wcf

I am working with Visual Studio 2010 and .NET 4.0. I created one web method and I am trying to call it with complex object (class object of class) as parameter but it raise error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object ". Please help me how to correct it.
WCF is as below:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void DoWork();

     [OperationContract]
    void RedirectDeposit(string TransactionId, Amount amount);
}

public class Service : IService
{
    public void DoWork()
    {

    }

    public void RedirectDeposit(string TransactionId, Amount amount)
    {
        string transactionId = "";
        string tranAmount = "";
        string tranCurrency = "";
        string exchangeRate = "";

        try
        {
            transactionId = TransactionId;
            tranAmount = amount.Amt;
            tranCurrency = amount.Currency;
            exchangeRate = amount.Rate.ExRate;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utility.LogMsg("Amount : " + ex.Message);
        }

    }
}

[DataContract]
public class Amount
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Amt { get; set;  }
    [DataMember]
    public string Currency {get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public ExchangeRate Rate { get; set; }

}

[DataContract]
public class ExchangeRate
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ExRate { get; set; }

}
```

Client call is as below:

```
playtechsrv.ServiceClient service = new ServiceClient();
Amount amount = new Amount();

try
{
      // Put user code to initialize the page here
      amount.Amt = "10";
      amount.Currency = "USD";
      amount.Rate.ExRate = "1255"; // Error happen here

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
      Utility.LogMsg(ex.Source);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line `amount.Rate.ExRate = "1255";` you're trying to assign a value to a property (`Rate`) which is not yet initialized. Hence you can't assign its property `ExRate`.

To make that work, you'll have to initialize `Rate` first:

```
amount.Rate = new ExchangeRate();
amount.Rate.ExRate = "1255";
```

Or combine the initialization and assignment:

```
amount.Rate = new ExchangeRate { ExRate = "1255" };
```